# Postgres batch insert with custom return value

Tags: postgresql-performance, batch-processing

I use Postgres 13 with Golan and pgx/v4 package for [batch](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/master/batch.go) insert items
Now we're migrating from UUID to serial ID's.

For one table with parent ID, I need to generate one sort of mapping of parentds ids, to put them on children's rows.

I split this insert in 2 batches,
In the first one, I do something like this:

```
batch.Queue(fmt.Sprintf("%s, %d", query, entity.TmpId), record.Values()...)
```

I think generated output is similar to this:

```
 insert into foo(txt) values ('a') returning id, 'key1' as externalKey;
```

After insert, I can generate this map of `entity.TmpId` and `serialId`.

The problem is in performance, before now to insert 1.5k rows It takes ~2 sec.

Now to insert only the parent's rows, which is less than 1.5k, it takes ~ 1 min.

I did a test to return only id col, or id and some static value and the performance is good, comparable to what we have at the moment.

At the moment, I want to generate this map using order of insert, although the documentation does not specify that this order will be [guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439293/is-insert-returning-guaranteed-to-return-things-in-the-right-order).

Or maybe you suggest me a better solution?

Here I created a [SQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2849140c5a4202addd1b89ca7b53ddb0)